# How to set up lock screen (with pin prompt) but not sleep after x minutes of inactivity?

Tags: windows

After x minutes of inactivity Windows 10 goes on sleep mode and requires pin. I don't want it to go to sleep mode (because I want my download programs to continue working for one thing) but I do want to prevent anybody from using my session, can I have the pin prompt with sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Set a screensaver**

Go to `Control Panel \ Appearance and Personalisation` and under `Personalisation`, pick `Change screensaver`.

Choose one screensaver, `Blank` or `[None]` if you don't want any animation that could consume power, and set the minutes you prefer to trigger the screensaver (and eventually lock the screen). Then, tick `On resume, display log-on screen`. Apply your changes.

**Extra**

To change when the computer sleeps to avoid any conflict when the computer locks the screen, go to `Control Panel \ Hardware and Sound` and under `Power Options`, pick `Change when the computer sleeps`, and set the minutes you prefer from the drop down list next to `Put the computer to sleep`

If you didn't set to use a PIN rather then passwords, go to the Start menu and click on your account on the top and pick `Change account settings`. Pick `Sign-in options` on the left. Click the button `Add` under `PIN`. Type in your account password and then set your PIN.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually lock your computer by hitting Win + L. This is especially helpful if you have to leave your desk often and for a short time.

You can combine manual locking with a locking screensaver as described just in case you forget to lock it.

Comment: Nice trick too I'll remember that!